# Riak simple query doesn't return data - Riak Java Client

Tags: scala, riak

The below snippet is rather simple, and by looking at others examples it should have worked

```
val result = client.mapReduce("some-users","firstName:Scala").execute
println(result.getResultRaw)// It just prints "[]"
```

But, the record with firstName:Scala actually is there in the bucket.

Running this code,

```
val result = client.mapReduce("some-users").execute ,it actually returns the key of the record
```

And when I check for the data using a rest client app, in my browser using

```
http://localhost:8098//riak/some-users/key
```

I get the required json data, which of course has "firstName" : "Scala", then why isn't the first snippet returning any values, I have turned 'riak_search' on, though I am using a riak java client for a scala based app it should not be posing any problems.

Does anyone have idea about why the snippet isn't working as it should. My riak version is 1.3.2 and Riak Java Client :- 1.1.4

Comment: Was search turned on before the data was added? Riak search doesn't index data that was added before it was enabled.  The issue may be with search, not mapreduce.  Try `curl http://localhost:8098/solr/preit-users/select?q=firstName:Scala`

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">0</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="indent">on</str>
      <str name="start">0</str>
      <str name="q">firstName:Scala</str>
      <str name="q.op">or</str>
      <str name="filter"></str>
      <str name="df">value</str>
      <str name="wt">standard</str>
      <str name="version">1.1</str>
      <str name="rows">0</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0" maxScore="0.0">
  </result>`
-The result

Comment: there's the issue: (`numFound="0"`), the search query is not finding any results so the mapreduce job had no input.

Comment: So what am I doing wrong, I am totally new to riak, so ..... Any solutions for me ... Any essential part of code i havent fullfilled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already got Riak up and running, you just need to get search going:

First make sure you have search enabled in your app.config file on every node in your cluster:

```
{riak_search, [
               {enabled, true}
              ]},
```

If you changed that you will need to restart Riak for it to take effect.

Then from the command line, install the search hook on the bucket you want indexed:

```
# search-cmd install testbucket
 :: Installing Riak Search <--> KV hook on bucket 'testbucket'.
```

At this point if there is already data in the bucket, it will ***not*** be indexed.  You will need to re-put any pre-existing data that you want indexed.

For a quick demonstration, I created 3 keys, creatively named 1,2, and 3; each containing a simple json object:

```
curl localhost:8098/buckets/testbucket/keys/1 -H "content-type: application/json" -XPUT \
 -d '{"firstName":"Tom", "color":"red"}'
curl localhost:8098/buckets/testbucket/keys/2 -H "content-type: application/json" -XPUT \
 -d '{"firstName":"Dick", "color":"green"}'
curl localhost:8098/buckets/testbucket/keys/3 -H "content-type: application/json" -XPUT \
 -d '{"firstName":"Harry", "color":"blue"}'
```

I can then query search to find the keys:

```
# curl http://localhost:8098/solr/testbucket/select\?q=firstName:Harry         
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">1</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="indent">on</str>
      <str name="start">0</str>
      <str name="q">firstName:Harry</str>
      <str name="q.op">or</str>
      <str name="filter"></str>
      <str name="df">value</str>
      <str name="wt">standard</str>
      <str name="version">1.1</str>
      <str name="rows">1</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" maxScore="0.353553">
    <doc>
      <str name="id">3
      </str>
      <str name="color">blue
      </str>
      <str name="firstName">Harry
      </str>
    </doc>
  </result>
</response>

# curl http://localhost:8098/solr/testbucket/select\?q=color:red%20or%20firstName:Harry
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">2</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="indent">on</str>
      <str name="start">0</str>
      <str name="q">color:red or firstName:Harry</str>
      <str name="q.op">or</str>
      <str name="filter"></str>
      <str name="df">value</str>
      <str name="wt">standard</str>
      <str name="version">1.1</str>
      <str name="rows">2</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="2" start="0" maxScore="0.143844">
    <doc>
      <str name="id">1
      </str>
      <str name="color">red
      </str>
      <str name="firstName">Tom
      </str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <str name="id">3
      </str>
      <str name="color">blue
      </str>
      <str name="firstName">Harry
      </str>
    </doc>
  </result>
</response>
```

I don't have a Scala install handy to whip up an example, but this should get you going in the right direction.

In case you haven't already seen them, the search docs are here:
http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/search/

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Joe which was easy-to-understand for a new user like me, seems like the part I left out was -> `search-cmd install testbucket`, and I hope now my riak java client will properly work as well, thank you again.